# Performance of the oracle table before and after adding new index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a table named TABLE1 with columns COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 & COLUMN4;

I have added 1 index on COLUMN1 and I want to add another index on COLUMN2. Before adding the second index, how do I test the performance of the TABLE1 before and after adding second index.
I  tried to research on it in Youtube and google but I am not able to find the correct information. Any lead would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: "I want to add another index on COLUMN2". Why? What *guides* you to that decision? Anyway, "testing" is simple: run some queries before (several times) - create index - run some queries after (several times) and compare the outcome. Don't forget to gather statistics and save explain plan so that you could compare them too.

Comment: How much data do you have in the table? Performance is based on your workload. You may want a particular query to run very fast but insert can be slow, for example. What performance benchmark are you trying to achieve (e.g. a particular select query should take no more than 100 ms to return results)?

Comment: Many process take the data from 1 table and effecting their performance. This table has 15 Million records

Comment: In the oracle world a table with 15 million rows, while not trivial, is really not all that significant. You assert "Many process take the data from 1 table and effecting their performance" but you have failed to _demonstrate_ or show evidence of exactly _what_ is "effecting their performance", or exactly _what process_ is being effected.  What, exactly, makes you think that adding this index is the proper solution to your problem, vs. say, partitioning the table, or rewriting a query.